# How to prevent user input-type change on prefilled passwords?

Tags: security, dom, browser, passwords

When making use of autocomplete, it can happen that passwords get prefilled into a input type=password field.

With normal interaction this password stays obscured. If however Somebody opens the code editor and changes the type to text, the password becomes visible.

I see this as a thread on shared devices. Is there any way of preventing this, without disabling autocomplete on this password field?
[image: Demonstration of autofilled password made visible]